# How to load redshift table from amazon s3 bucket excel file using copy commands?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

In my S3 bucket I have .xls file (this file is grouped file, I mean first 20 row having some image and some extract details about client).

So first I want to convert .xls into .csv then I load Redshift table through copy commands and ignore first 20 rows also.

**Note:** I manualy save as .xls into .csv then I try to load Redshift
table through copy commands is successfully loaded. Now my problem is
how to convert .xls into .csv through Pentaho jobs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please edit your Question to provide additional information to explain what you are trying to achieve? For example, how is the data being generated, how is it getting into Amazon S3, are you currently able to call any Amazon Redshift COPY commands? What have you tried, what problems are you facing? What format are the files? Amazon Redshift can only load delimited (eg CSV), fixed-width or JSON file formats.

Comment: @John Thank you,Is't possible to convert .xls file into .csv through pentaho jobs ?

Answer (score -2):

You can convert excel to csv by using transformation with just two steps inside:

1. Microsoft Excel input - it should read rows from your excel file
2. Text file output - it saves rows from step 1 to csv file

[image]